# ADB is not working after android studio update

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

I have updated android studio to Android Studio v2.3.3 (June 2017) and adb stopped showing logs when I launch app on android studio emulator

The log shows:

```
07/11 13:08:17: Launching app
```

$ adb push C:\Users\1\AndroidStudioProjects\Don'tWakeMeApp4\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/oleksandr.ivanets.dontwakemeapp
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/oleksandr.ivanets.dontwakemeapp"
Success

$ adb shell am start -n "oleksandr.ivanets.dontwakemeapp/oleksandr.ivanets.dontwakemeapp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 4429 on device Nexus_5X_API_26 [emulator-5554]

Comment: does `adb logcat` launched from the command line show anything?

Comment: where is the command line?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Comment: Thank you, I have found the problem, it works but through Android Monitor.

Answer (score 6):

Click on below link

http://adbshell.com/downloads

and download the first link with name ADB Kits ( contains adb.exe and necessary .dll files).

After downloading replace these files with the ones in the path

> Android/Sdk/platform-tools/

Now click on adb.exe and it will open cmd and will start the adb server.

Now it will detect the device and no problem. OOOOOllllaaaaa.....

> If the Problem persists again then do the same... save the folder
>   somewhere.... just replace files... it will detect the device
>   automatically then

Answer (score 1):

***Preface: Although my answer focuses on Android Studio's perspective of ADB errors, I'm sure it is helpful for Windows ADB debugging in general!***

@sHaRkBoY 's answer helped me look in the right direction. I used to get **"Unable to detect adb version, adb output:"** on Android Studio while trying to "run" the app onto the phone...  and no devices showed up when phone was connected to PC.

I had tried all these (from different SO answers) **but none of them worked!!!**:

- "Invalidate cache and restart" from `File` toolbar.
- Turn off and turn on USB debugging on phone multiple times
- Experimented with "MTP", "PTP", "Midi" and "Charging" modes to see if ADB detects something...
- Checked my anti-virus software to see if adding exceptions to the adb directory works...
- Installed various unnecessary C++ re-distributables
- Tried a different USB cable (and USB port)
- Restarted Android Studio and PC
- and even uninstalled and re-installed Android studio!

---

The problem finally was that the `platform_tools\adb.exe` file downloaded by the official SDK tool manager was corrupted! So I used to get windows error code 0xc0000142 on launching adb.exe from command prompt! :(

### SOLUTION:

For future readers (and victims xD) of the above ADB problem, please do the following:

1. Firstly, add the `platform_tools\` directory into the system path environment variable.
2. Go ahead and replace the following 3 files in your `platform_tools` (`C:\Users\{YourAccount}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`) directory. (Please backup the same folder before, just in case.)

[ADB kit (internal version number: 32)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p7DiAcH2KisRw8NE_V_-s8zibKd3CDvl)

---

**Note**: Please prefer this ADB kit (exe and dll files), compared to @sHaRkBoY 's ADB kit (2.0.0.0), since it has an updated version of `AdbWinUsbApi.dll` (2.0.0.1), where a race condition issue has been fixed!

[I hope my answer saves your from the traumatic experience I went through while troubleshooting magical ADB for an entire day!](https://media.boingboing.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/giphy-3.gif) :)